# Running dotnet pack exports the nupkg with the wrong name

Tags: .net-core

I'm calling the following via command line and from the project.json:-

```
dotnet pack --no-build --configuration Release -o packages
```

But the resulting nupkg file is: `{parentfoldername}.x.x.x.x.nupkg`

I would like to either set the name of the section `{parentfoldername}` or get it to use the resulting assembly name that is being included.

Can anyone shed some light on this as this seems subtlety different to nuget pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the name of the project, and this also the name of the package by specifying `"name"` in your project.json. Though this would also change the name of the DLL file, assuming you didn't override that in some other way.